# Graphic issues with live Ubuntu

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, live-environment

When I try to launch live Ubuntu *(tried 17.04 and 16.04)* from USB on my computer, the screen's flickering and then turns into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8POet.jpg).

I've experienced some issues with ubuntu on this computer before **(but not on a live version)**, which could be solved by entering tty and reinstalling drivers. However, on a live version it doesn't work now, it ignores all key inputs.

*Nvidia GTX 970 from Gigabyte*